# How to determine if KeyCode is printable character

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard

I am handling the key down event on one of my controls. If the key pressed is an actual input (alphabetic, numeric, or symbol of some kind) I want to append it to a string I have. If it is a control character (enter, escape, etc..) I don't want to do anything.

Is there a quick and easy way to determine if the key code is a printable character or a control character?

Currently I am doing

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
      {
        e.Handled = false;
        return;
      }
```

But I know there are probably a few more keys I don't care about that do something important in the system handler, so I don't want to handle them.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you only want printable characters, then you probably don't want `OnKeyDown`.  You should be using `OnKeyPress` instead, which is called *only* for printable characters (more or less), and applies translations for modifier keys (Shift, primarily).

I said "more or less" above, because you will also get control characters, which aren't necessarily *printable*.  Those can easily be filtered out with `char.IsControl`, though.

```
protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e){
    if(!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)){
        // do something with printable character
    }
}
```

Something that's easy to overlook in a design like this is the backspace key.  Typically, the best behavior upon receiving a backspace character (`'\b'`, or `(char)8`) is to remove the last character from your buffer.  It's easy to forget to do this.

Answer (score 6):

If you handle the `KeyPress` event instead of `KeyDown`, the `KeyPressEventArgs` will have a [KeyChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.keychar.aspx) property. That will reduce the number of "extra" key events you get. You can then use something like `char.IsLetterOrDigit` or [char.IsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iscontrol.aspx) to filter what you want.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you only have the `KeyCode`, you can trying P/Invoking into the [MapVirtualKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646306%28VS.85%29.aspx) function. I'm not sure if this will work for all cultures.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern int MapVirtualKey(int uCode, int uMapType);

public static bool RepresentsPrintableChar(this Keys key)
{
   return !char.IsControl((char)MapVirtualKey((int)key, 2));
}
```

---

```
Console.WriteLine(Keys.Shift.RepresentsPrintableChar());
Console.WriteLine(Keys.Enter.RepresentsPrintableChar());
Console.WriteLine(Keys.Divide.RepresentsPrintableChar());
Console.WriteLine(Keys.A.RepresentsPrintableChar());
```

Output:

```
false
false
true
true
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this function, you might want to cast `char` to `byte` (or simply edit the function):

```
bool IsPrintable(byte item)
{
    // Range of chars from space till ~ (tilda)
    return item >= 32 && item < 126;
}
```

Comment: This would only work for latin printable characters. It completely ignores all other alphabets and misses a lot of printable symbols. Also casting from char to byte will discard information. C# chars are 16bit.