# Is there any explanation for WPF Key enumeration?

Tags: c#, wpf, keydown

I'm looking at [key enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.key%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but for some of the codes the description isn't very explanatory. For example: `Key.ImeProcessed`. Is there any list where I can get better explanation for most of the `enumeration` if not all?

I am trying to filter out `KeyPress` that doesn't make any change to the text (e.g. <kbd>alt</kbd>/<kbd>ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>arrow</kbd> keys) I wanted to see if these buttons fall into some category (like `Key.DoesNotModifyText`)

Comment: Might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639163/how-to-determine-if-keycode-is-printable-character

Comment: @keyboardP unfortunately that's for winform, not wpf

Answer (score 0):

The WPF Key Codes are based, I believe, on the [Win32 virtual key codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx), which are quite extensive.

IME is an **Input Method Editor**, which you can read about [here, at Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/input-method-editors). These make it easier to write in languages (such as Chinese) which are not easily written on a standard keyboard. The various IME codes indicate the state of an IME, if one is installed.

Comment: Funny enough is that the `Key` enum for WPF doesn't respects the numeric values from the Windows API, while the matching enum for WinForms follows it closely. No idea why they screwed everything for WPF.